# Woocommerce: Adding customizable product seperatly to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have product with a custom field. This custom field will be filled by the user (add a custom text).

The problem now is, if the user want to buy twice the same product but with different text, the product will be shown in the cart and also in the order as 1 product with the quantity of 2, instead of two separate products.

Variable product is not an option as every user can enter in the text field whatever they want.

I really digged in to the code, but I don't find the point where I could hook in to.

Comment: Depends on how you've coded the custom field. If you've added the field in `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` then I think the items should be coming up as unique. Alternatively, there is [product add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons)

Comment: @helgatheviking I found it out. It is actually a bug of the WooCommerce Multilingual Plugin which removed the new new item in $this->cart_contents. 8 hours of my life... oh boy..

Comment: Good catch. WooCommerce multilingual has been known to cause a lot of issues.